# Is there a way to not let the flask raise a "no-response" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My task is to count the number of times a client in a network requests for service and send the response only on the 5th request. My application is in Flask and my code looks like:

```
count = 0
@test.route('/testurl/<par>', methods=["GET"])
def fun(par):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        global count
        count += 1
        if count == 5:
            return jsonify({"data": "something"})
```

Clearly, if the count is not equal to 5, the function won't send any response and flask will raise an error. I just want to suppress the error and not show it in the terminal because my code is working fine. I'm not sure how to use try-except in this and don't know about any decorator which can do this. Can somebody help?

Comment: In HTTP no response is considered an error.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, I agree. I just want to handle it, if possible, using try-except or any decorator.

Comment: Maybe you want to send back an appropriate HTTP status code like 503.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks. I'll do this.

Comment: @KenKinder it does. Thanks a lot